# Create row level trigger that computes the total salary for each newly inserted employee

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I need to Create a row level trigger that computes the total salary for each newly inserted employee - trigger before insert and before update of the salary or bonus fields. I also need to Use the :NEW fields to store the data.

So far I have: I cant really figure out how to display the total salary, I believe I set up the beginning right, just not sure about the rest after FOR EACH ROW WHEN

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER 
TRG_Step3_TotSalary
BEFORE UPDATE OF salary, bonus ON Lab12_Employees
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (Salary + Bonus = :NEW.TotalSalary);
BEGIN 
INSERT :NEW.Salary + bonus
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Salary =' || (:NEW.TotalSalary);
```

Comment: why you need `WHEN` wouldnt you need update whatever Salary or Bonus change? So just `FOR EACH ROW`

Comment: hmm yeah I could do an update I was just worried updating an update – and getting a recursive trigger

Answer (score 0):

Untested but I belive the below should work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER 
TRG_Step3_TotSalary
BEFORE UPDATE OF salary, bonus ON Lab12_Employees
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  :NEW.TotalSalary := :NEW.Salary + bonus
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Salary =' || (:NEW.TotalSalary);
END
```

Comment: yeah this doesnt work :/ syntax errors in the begin statement ugh

Comment: What is the error? I think that we will need :NEW.bonus rather than just bonus in the first line after the begin, but the error message will help to clarify

Comment: semi colon missing 
```:NEW.TotalSalary := :NEW.Salary + bonus```
should be 
```:NEW.TotalSalary := :NEW.Salary + bonus;```